# Type 'T | "queryKey"' cannot be used to index type 'FuncParams<T>'.(2536)

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, typescript-generics

I want to define a function parameter that satisfies the following two conditions:

1. It must contain a `keyword` field.
2. It must contain another field which name is the value of the `keyword` field.
3. When the `keyword` field is not passed, it should default to the value `queryKey`.

Here is my uncompleted code:

```js
type QueryKey<Keyword extends string> = {
  [key in Keyword]: string;
};

type FuncParams<T extends string> = QueryKey<T> & {
    keyword?: T;
}

function testFunc<T extends string>(query: FuncParams<T>) {
    const {
        keyword = 'queryKey',
    } = query;
    
    // error: Type 'T | "queryKey"' cannot be used to index type 'FuncParams<T>'.(2536)
    console.log(query[keyword]);

    // Use type assertion to indicate that keyword will always have a value
    // compile ok, but I don't want use type assertion directly, like the next line:
    console.log(query[keyword as keyof FuncParams<T>]);
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiA0hEAeNIDuB7RAEyggA9gIA7QgZyhuEQEtKBzAPigF4oBvAKChQA2gGt0UFlGz4iAXQBc9Ri1YBufgF8N-UJCgAxOJQDGABQCGiCwFsaGAColyVWsuZtOPeElTpHnABkfIJCUOK4BIQA-EoOGpr8-ABmxibATHiUUBQMRqaOzhTUdAweHAAUAI4IyEr55la29g7sAJQhYVAmWQydXWERssQ8AOQ1vtijADShQprcUBPIGl1zUAD0GySIiARx4NCjTgA+UABEy34g56PdFpSUeMBQAEbQcDQQxMB4ktRkHKHKCjBqWax2AKjAB0FQATABWADMADY2usepQaHgADYQaE4vCsaq1EBidDDORtHRdLZQACqXyB+gsNC+iAyWRyfxYhCYJgsFByAAtBeEKVEoDgmDicVALDicBYQHRRQA3aAWKBqhUIdZ0gCSUEIWVGLyVlBen2gek1bKQnOyfMQEHSOJA0ygOKY4hF0EoZBe3oDCgxvVx+MJxKu5MiRHldAieGShjS4OaASpCSAA)

I expect to make compile pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ensure that the type of keyword is the key of QueryKey as follows.

```
type QueryKey<Keyword extends string> = {
  [key in Keyword]: string;
};

type FuncParams<T extends string> = QueryKey<T> & {
    keyword?: T;
}

function testFunc<T extends string>(query: FuncParams<T>) {
    const {
        keyword = 'queryKey' as T,
    } = query;
    
    // error: Type 'T | "queryKey"' cannot be used to index type 'FuncParams<T>'.(2536)
    console.log(query[keyword]);

    // Use type assertion to indicate that keyword will always have a value
    // I don't want use type assertion directly, like the next line:
    console.log(query[keyword as keyof FuncParams<T>]);
}
```